# How To Get Cookie from Client Side (Qooxdoo) when Server set HttpOnly and Secure flags to True?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a question about using Cookie in Qooxdoo. Currently my enterprise application use qooxdoo for client side, and we use Cookie to store the localization sent from server. We have had a vulnerable report for HttpOnly and Secure flags, so we enabled the from server. And the result, the cookie is hidden from client side, we have use qx.bom.Cookie.get(), but this function has not worked any more because the cookie hidden now. So, my question, is there is any to get cookie when server set HttpOnly and Secure flags to True ? If yes, could you please instruct a little bit ? Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Khoa Tran

Answer (score 1):

By design when the flag HttpOnly appears for a cookie then is inaccessible to JavaScript's Document.cookie API. This is happening to prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

By using the Secure flag for a cookie you inform the browser to this cookie the server only with a encrypted request (HTTPS); so even if a MITM is occurring somewhere in the network it will be harder for the attackers to get access to this cookie.

More information about httponly and secure flags [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#What_is_HttpOnly.3F)

In order to be able to read the localization settings you should split the information into multiple cookies. You should store the information about the session management in a secure httponly cookie (probably some kind of token) and the rest of the information in another cookie (without httponly flag) that will have personalization settings.

Comment: You're right, Stelios. Thanks so much for pointing out this solution, I have separated session management and cookie into different cookies, and it works now.